# Using tar to update archive with files from a while loop?

Tags: shell-script, tar

I have the problem listed here: [Oct 2019 upgrade: pip upgrade failure · Issue #5844 · msys2/MINGW-packages](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/5844): basically, `pip` on MSYS2 refuses to update because it sees some files. `pacman -Syu` basically dumps this:

```
...
:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
:: Retrieving packages...
 mingw-w64-x86_64-gl...     4.6 MiB  4.97M/s 00:01 [#####################] 100%
 mingw-w64-x86_64-gn...  1942.9 KiB  1045K/s 00:02 [#####################] 100%
(18/18) checking keys in keyring                   [#####################] 100%
(18/18) checking package integrity                 [#####################] 100%
(18/18) loading package files                      [#####################] 100%
(18/18) checking for file conflicts                [#####################] 100%
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
python2-pip: /c/msys64/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/debug.py exists in filesystem
python2-pip: /c/msys64/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/debug.pyc exists in filesystem
...
```

I don't want to uninstall pip, and it seems ([pacman "exists on filesystem" error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240252/pacman-exists-on-filesystem-error)) that I can "just" move the files elsewhere, then have the update run. Of course, I'd like to preserve the original file locations, of the files that I'm moving.

So, I thought, maybe I could `tar` those files in an archive (using `--remove-files` so the originals are also deleted, so they don't trip the update any more), then restore them after update - if any other packages I need, have installed them.

Unfortunately, I really cannot find the right invocation, so that a `tar` archive is update with files that come in from a `while` loop (that is, I don't have a "one-line", space-separated list of files).

This results with only a single file in archive:

```
$ pacman -Syu | grep exists | awk '{print $2}' | while read f; do tar -czf /tmp/bckp.tar "$f"; done
:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
...

$ tar tzvf /tmp/bckp.tar
-rw-r--r-- user/None       13854 2019-09-02 09:07 c/msys64/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages/rfc3986/validators.py
```

This won't even run:

```
$ pacman -Syu | grep exists | awk '{print $2}' | while read f; do tar -czvf --strip-components=1 --append /tmp/bckp.tar.gz "$f"; done
:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
tar: You may not specify more than one '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or  '--test-label' option
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
tar: You may not specify more than one '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or  '--test-label' option
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
...
```

This won't either:

```
$ pacman -Syu | grep exists | awk '{print $2}' | while read f; do tar -zvf --strip-components=1 --append /tmp/bckp.tar.gz "$f"; done
:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
tar: Cannot update compressed archives
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
tar: Cannot update compressed archives
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
...
```

This ends up complaining "no such file or directory" for existing files:

```
$ pacman -Syu | grep exists | awk '{print $2}' | while read f; do tar -vf --strip-components=1 --append /tmp/bckp.tar.gz "$f"; done
:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /tmp/bckp.tar.gz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
/c/msys64/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/debug.py
tar: Removing leading `/' from hard link targets
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /tmp/bckp.tar.gz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
/c/msys64/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/debug.pyc
...
```

So, assuming I have a list of files (absolute filepaths), of the form `/c/msys64/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/debug.pyc`, in a `while` loop - how can I add them all to a `.tar` archive, such that they end up in it with the first part of the absolute path stripped (i.e. mentioned file would end up in `tar` archive as `msys64/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/debug.pyc`)?

Comment: Do you *need* a loop? Using `xargs`, you can run tar on a number of filenames at once.

Comment: Thanks, @muru - not sure I need a loop, but then, how else would I extract the output from `pacman` - which contains the files I want to move? I'm trying `pacman -Syu | grep exists | awk '{print $2}' | xargs tar -vf --strip-components=1 /tmp/bckp.tar` and it fails with `tar: You must specify one of the '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or '--test-label' options`; also tried `pacman -Syu | grep exists | awk '{print $2}' | xargs tar -cvf --strip-components=1 /tmp/bckp.tar`, fails with `tar: /tmp/bckp.tar: Cannot stat: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I finally found the right invocation - note, the `sed` is added because `--strip-components` works on extraction *only*; so here we strip the `/c/` manually from the filepath strings, and then instruct `tar` to change directory to `/c/` using the `-C` switch:

```
$ pacman -Syu | grep exists | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's_/c/__' | xargs tar -cvf /tmp/bckp.tar -C /c/
:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
msys64/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/debug.py
msys64/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/debug.pyc
msys64/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/__init__.py
msys64/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/__init__.pyc
...
```

... and to double-check:

```
$ tar tvf /tmp/bckp.tar
-rw-r--r-- user/None        3360 2019-09-02 09:08 msys64/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/debug.py
-rw-r--r-- user/None        4154 2019-09-02 09:08 msys64/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/debug.pyc
-rw-r--r-- user/None         861 2019-09-02 09:08 msys64/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/__init__.py
-rw-r--r-- user/None         986 2019-09-02 09:08 msys64/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/__init__.pyc
...
```